# htaccess redirect entire folder and all its subfolders to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect a folder and all the subfolders to a subdomain root for all folders and their subfolders.

As an example, I want the main folder and its subfolders:

```
www.example.com/folder/
www.example.com/folder/sub_folder
www.example.com/folder/sub_folder/sub_sub_folder
```

**ALL** to redirect to

```
xyz.example.com
```

and **NOT**

```
xyz.example.com/sub_folder
xyz.example.com/sub_folder/sub_sub_folder
```

Please suggest an htaccess rule that can do this..

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect all folders and subfolder (excluding the homepage) to subdomain.

Comment: I actually just need the 'folder' and all the sub-directories to redirect to xyz.example.com and not the other folders on my site. I've edited my question to make this a bit more clearer.